# Implementing @tillpos/xml-escpos-helper in React Native from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

how implement @tillpos/xml-escpos-helper in react native? I have the code in nodejs. But i cant connect nodejs to react native. I have not found any documentation.p

I have used [this code](https://medium.com/till-engineering/receipt-printing-with-esc-pos-a-javascript-cross-platform-library-7110d7f7a1db) to connect the printer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.